# How to use pearson correlation to calculate a probability

Tags: correlation

I am using this to bet sports.

I have a database of basketball quarter total scores, and whether the quarter total was over or under the market total.

I used =Pearson in excel to calculate the correlation coefficient, and found that quarters 1 and 3 have a .0677 correlation coefficient.

I calculate my own probabilities that, independently, quarter 1 and quarter 3 will go over or under the market total.

So say I expect quarter 1 to go over the market total 55% of the time, and quarter 3 to go over the market total 50% of the time, if these events were independent, I would just calculate the joint probability of both going over as 50% * 55% = 27.5%.

My question is: **what do I actually do with the .0677 correlation coefficient to update my calculation above**

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve and how does computing the Pearson correlation help you solve it?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the probability that the total score of Quarter 1 of a basketball game scores over a number, and Quarter 3 does too. I have probabilities for each event, and would normally multiply them together to find the joint probability. But I know the events are not independent. I found that out by calculating the Parson correlation. But now that I have the pearson correlation, how do I incorporate that in a formula for joint probability of dependent events?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

The Pearson correlation coefficient does not supply enough information to give you this probability, without some assumption about the distribution concerned.

In your database, you can count the number of times the event you are interest in occurs. This is an estimate of its probability. If the database is large enough, it is a good estimate.

Doing anything else involves making an assumption about how baseball scores are distributed.

Comment: Ok I thought about it and you're absolutely right